# Brew installation fails due to Ruby versioning?

Tags: arch-linux, homebrew, brew, garuda-linux

I am trying to install [Linux Brew](https://brew.sh) on [Garuda Linux](https://garudalinux.org) (Arch Linux based distro) but the install script fails with the following error:

```
==> Pouring portable-ruby-2.6.8.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Failed to install ruby 2.6.8!
Error: Failed to install Homebrew Portable Ruby and cannot find another Ruby 2.6.8!
If there's no Homebrew Portable Ruby available for your processor:
- install Ruby 2.6.8 with your system package manager (or rbenv/ruby-build)
- make it first in your PATH
- try again

Failed during: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

I verified that Ruby exists on the system:

```
➜ ruby --version
ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x86_64-linux]
```

Is it complaining that Brew wants a particular version? I found [one](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1482948) or [two](https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/t9zs67/homebrew_help_on_new_manjaro_install/) other users who posted the same error in recent days. The latter is also an Arch-based system and got the suggestion to install `pkgconf`, which I verified is installed on my system.

```
➜ pkgconf --version
1.8.0
```

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is ... any suggestions? I am new to Arch Linux based distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps someone else:

I ended up installing [`rbenv`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rbenv) abd [`ruby-build`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ruby-build) following instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_User_Repository#Installing_and_upgrading_packages). Following that, I set up rbenv shell integration with `rbenv init` (for bash specifically, since [brew install](https://brew.sh) uses bash). Then I installed the required version of ruby using `rbenv install` command and then switched to it globally by running `rbenv global`. After this brew (finally!!) installed successfully and I switched back to the system version of ruby.

I hope I don't have to switch ruby versions each time I use Brew though ...